# How to prevent image float when resizing bootstrap layout

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive

We have a typical bootstrap SPA that we turned into a React site.

In one of the sections there's an image that appears in the right side of the layout, and it spans the section vertically (takes up about 50% horizontally).

When the window is reduced in size, at some intermediary positions, the image no longer spans the section vertically, making it float above what looks like a margin or a frame, but in fact, it's just the background color of the section whose aspect ratio is not enough to hold the image completely.

Is there a way to prevent this? It seems like the only solution would be to pick images that are have aspect ratios that are more amenable to the half the grid position they are being given.

Comment: Can we get an example bootply?

Comment: Will try that out thanks..

Comment: Here is the boot ply: https://www.bootply.com/83HvOCIZwO @Ravimallya

Comment: @Ravimallya that worked, add it as an answer and I will check it.